# How to compare old and new field values in a CLR insert and update trigger

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, triggers, sqlclr

We are considering suing some SQL CLR triggers to populate our audit log for certain tables, I know how to register the CLR assembly and trigger in the server and all works fine when I know which columns to look for and if I have to just do an insert of a new record in the audit log table.

now we would like this to be independent from the *monitored* table schema so that we do not need to edit and re-deploy the trigger at every new column added or renamed to the source table, I would like to persist in my audit table something simple like n XML column containing a snapshot of the changes, something like:

```
<AuditEntry ObjectName='TableName' ObjectId='1'>
    <Field='Firstname'>
        <OldValue>David</OldValue>
        <NewValue>Davide</NewValue>
    </Field>
    <Field='Email'>
        <OldValue/>
        <NewValue>aaa.b@gmail.com</NewValue>
    </Field>
</AuditEntry>
```

this XML is just an example, I only need to understand how to write my trigger C# code so taht it compares the old and the new row field by field getting old value and new value then I know how to dump this in an XML document.

thanks a lot,
Davide.

Answer (score 2):

I did some tests and I was able to solve this myself, here the whole story for the sake of sharing it ;-)

**1)** .NET SQL CLR Trigger, 1 trigger only which will be listening to two tables, the only assumption is that watched tables have an identity column called **Id**

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Xml;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

namespace Axis.CLR.SampleObjects
{
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlTypes;
    using System.Text;

    public partial class AuditTrigger
    {
        public const string GetTableContextStatement =
            "SELECT object_name(resource_associated_entity_id) FROM sys.dm_tran_locks WHERE request_session_id = @@spid and resource_type = 'OBJECT'";

        [SqlTrigger(Name = "UserNameAudit", Target = "Users", Event = "FOR INSERT")]
        public static void UserNameAudit()
        {
            SqlTriggerContext triggContext = SqlContext.TriggerContext;

            //SqlPipe sqlP = SqlContext.Pipe;

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
            using (SqlCommand sqlComm = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                conn.Open();

                // Gets a reference to the affected table name
                string tableName = string.Empty;
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(GetTableContextStatement, conn))
                {
                    tableName = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                }

                // STORING INSERT AUDIT

                if (triggContext.TriggerAction == TriggerAction.Insert)
                {
                    #region handling INSERT action

                    sqlComm.CommandText = "SELECT * from INSERTED";
                    var reader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();

                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        XmlDocument finalDocument = new XmlDocument();

                        XmlNode rootElement = finalDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, tableName, string.Empty);

                        XmlAttribute newAttribute = finalDocument.CreateAttribute("Id");
                        newAttribute.Value = reader.GetInt64(reader.GetOrdinal("Id")).ToString();
                        rootElement.Attributes.Append(newAttribute);

                        newAttribute = finalDocument.CreateAttribute("Operation");
                        newAttribute.Value = "INSERT";
                        rootElement.Attributes.Append(newAttribute);

                        finalDocument.AppendChild(rootElement);

                        XmlNode createdElement = finalDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Fields", string.Empty);

                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            XmlNode fieldElement = finalDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, reader.GetName(i), string.Empty);

                            if (reader.IsDBNull(i))
                            {
                                fieldElement.InnerText = "NULL";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                fieldElement.InnerText = reader.GetValue(i).ToString();
                            }

                            createdElement.AppendChild(fieldElement);
                        }

                        // Node was added
                        rootElement.AppendChild(createdElement);

                        // Adds the Audit

                        sqlComm.CommandText = "[dbo].[AddAuditTrail]";
                        sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        SqlParameter xmlParamA = new SqlParameter("@ObjectId", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                        xmlParamA.Value = reader.GetInt64(reader.GetOrdinal("Id"));
                        sqlComm.Parameters.Add(xmlParamA);

                        reader.Close();

                        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ObjectName", tableName);

                        SqlParameter xmlParamB = new SqlParameter("@TraceXML", SqlDbType.Xml);
                        xmlParamB.Value = new SqlXml(new XmlTextReader(finalDocument.OuterXml, XmlNodeType.Document, null));
                        sqlComm.Parameters.Add(xmlParamB);

                        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuditType", "INSERT");

                        sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        //sqlP.Send(string.Format("Generated AFTER INSERT XML is: '{0}'", finalDocument.OuterXml));
                    }

                    #endregion handling INSERT action
                }
                else if (triggContext.TriggerAction == TriggerAction.Update)
                {
                    #region handling UPDATE action

                    DataSet values = new DataSet();
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlComm);

                    sqlComm.CommandText = "SELECT * from INSERTED";
                    adapter.Fill(values, "INSERTED");

                    sqlComm.CommandText = "SELECT * from DELETED";
                    adapter.Fill(values, "DELETED");

                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                    builder.Append("<Fields>");

                    int recordId = 0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < values.Tables["INSERTED"].Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string colName = values.Tables["INSERTED"].Columns[i].ColumnName;

                        if (colName.ToLower().Equals("id"))
                        {
                            recordId = Convert.ToInt32(values.Tables["DELETED"].Rows[0][i]);

                            builder.AppendFormat("<Id value='{0}' />", recordId);
                        }

                        // if both nulls or both the same, no audit needed...

                        if (values.Tables["INSERTED"].Rows[0].IsNull(i) && values.Tables["DELETED"].Rows[0].IsNull(i))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (values.Tables["INSERTED"].Rows[0][i].Equals(values.Tables["DELETED"].Rows[0][i]))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        builder.AppendFormat("<{0}>", colName);

                        // DUMPING OLD VALUE
                        builder.Append("<OldValue>");

                        if (values.Tables["DELETED"].Rows[0].IsNull(i))
                        {
                            builder.Append("NULL");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            builder.Append(values.Tables["DELETED"].Rows[0][i]);
                        }

                        builder.Append("</OldValue>");

                        // DUMPING NEW VALUE
                        builder.Append("<NewValue>");

                        if (values.Tables["INSERTED"].Rows[0].IsNull(i))
                        {
                            builder.Append("NULL");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            builder.Append(values.Tables["INSERTED"].Rows[0][i]);
                        }

                        builder.Append("</NewValue>");

                        builder.AppendFormat("</{0}>", colName);
                    }

                    builder.Append("</Fields>");

                    builder.Insert(0, string.Format("<{0} Id='{1}' Operation='{2}'>", tableName, recordId, "UPDATE"));
                    builder.AppendFormat("</{0}>", tableName);

                    // Adds the Audit

                    sqlComm.CommandText = "[dbo].[AddAuditTrail]";
                    sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    SqlParameter xmlParamA = new SqlParameter("@ObjectId", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                    xmlParamA.Value = recordId;
                    sqlComm.Parameters.Add(xmlParamA);

                    sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ObjectName", tableName);

                    SqlParameter xmlParamB = new SqlParameter("@TraceXML", SqlDbType.Xml);
                    xmlParamB.Value = new SqlXml(new XmlTextReader(builder.ToString(), XmlNodeType.Document, null));
                    sqlComm.Parameters.Add(xmlParamB);

                    sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuditType", "UPDATE");

                    sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //sqlP.Send(string.Format("Generated AFTER UPDATE XML is: '{0}'", builder.ToString()));

                    #endregion handling UPDATE action
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**2)** here the SQL code I used to register the trigger on the sql server and link it to two different tables (Users and Products), there is only 1 CLR trigger but in the SQL server two triggers are created as External using the CLR one, each one for each table

```
USE [Axis_Davide]
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION SCRIPT
---------------------------------

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'trAuditTriggerA') AND type in (N'TA'))
BEGIN
    DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[trAuditTriggerA]
        PRINT('Trigger A was removed');
END

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'trAuditTriggerB') AND type in (N'TA'))
BEGIN
    DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[trAuditTriggerB]
        PRINT('Trigger B was removed');
END


IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.assemblies asms WHERE asms.name = N'Axis.CLR.SampleObjects' and is_user_defined = 1)
BEGIN
    DROP ASSEMBLY [Axis.CLR.SampleObjects]
    PRINT('Assembly was removed');
END

CREATE ASSEMBLY [Axis.CLR.SampleObjects]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 'C:\Axis\SQLCLR_Samples\Axis.CLR.SampleObjects.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
PRINT('Assembly was created');

EXEC('CREATE TRIGGER trAuditTriggerA ON [dbo].[Users] AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS EXTERNAL NAME [Axis.CLR.SampleObjects].[Axis.CLR.SampleObjects.AuditTrigger].[UserNameAudit]')
PRINT('Trigger A was created');

EXEC('CREATE TRIGGER trAuditTriggerB ON [dbo].[Products] AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS EXTERNAL NAME [Axis.CLR.SampleObjects].[Axis.CLR.SampleObjects.AuditTrigger].[UserNameAudit]')
PRINT('Trigger B was created');

---------------------------------
COMMIT TRANSACTION SCRIPT
```

**3)** here the create statement for my audit table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AuditTrail]
(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AuditDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [ObjectId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ObjectName] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [TraceXML] [xml] NOT NULL,
    [TraceSize] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AuditType] [nvarchar](16) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AuditTrail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [Id] ASC )
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AuditTrail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_AuditTrail_AuditDate]  DEFAULT (sysutcdatetime()) FOR [AuditDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AuditTrail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_AuditTrail_UserName]  DEFAULT (suser_sname()) FOR [UserName]
GO
```

**4)** here the stored procedure called by the trigger to add a new audit record on each insert / update

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddAuditTrail]
    @ObjectId bigint, 
    @ObjectName nvarchar(128),
    @TraceXML xml,
    @AuditType nvarchar(16)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[AuditTrail] ([ObjectId], [ObjectName], [TraceXML], [TraceSize], [AuditType])
        VALUES (@ObjectId, @ObjectName, @TraceXML, DATALENGTH(@TraceXML), @AuditType)
END
GO
```

**5)** the content of my audit table looks like the following, for an `INSERT` and for an `UPDATE`

```
<Users Id="51" Operation="INSERT">
  <Fields>
    <UserName>Davide</UserName>
    <Pass>Test</Pass>
    <Id>51</Id>
    <Email>NULL</Email>
  </Fields>
</Users>

<Users Id="51" Operation="UPDATE">
  <Fields>
    <Id value="51" />
    <Email>
      <OldValue>NULL</OldValue>
      <NewValue>@</NewValue>
    </Email>
  </Fields>
</Users>
```